# Running FGSEA, Data in incorrect format: pathways should be a list with each element containing names of the stats argument

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am attempting to Run FGSEA against my DESEQ2 data anD the Ribosome database obtained from msigDB
However I am recieving the following error:

```
type> fgseaRes <- fgsea(gmt.file, res, minSize=15, maxSize=500) #need to load GOCC_RIBOSOME pathway
Error in preparePathwaysAndStats(pathways, stats, minSize, maxSize, gseaParam,  : 
  pathways should be a list with each element containing names of the stats argument here
```

Suggesting either the pathway or stats I've imported into R are in the incorrect format.

MY Current code reads as:

```
##loading ranks

res <- read.delim ("Rank_fgsea_data.rnk", header=T, colClasses = c("numeric", "character"))

#removing decimals
res$Gene.ID <- gsub("\\..*", "", res$Gene.ID)

#read as list/data frame

as.data.frame(res)

res <- setnames(res$log2FoldChange, res$Gene.ID)
str(res)

## Loading pathways from msigDB

pathways <- gmtPathways(gmt.file)
str(head(pathways))
as.data.frame(pathways)

##running FGSEA

fgseaRes <- fgsea(gmt.file, res, minSize=15, maxSize=500) #need to load GOCC_RIBOSOME pathway
head(fgseaRes)
```

I would be grateful for any advice on this subject as I am new to R.

I have attempted to read my data as a list using

```
as.data.frame(res)
```

but this has not helped.

Comment: A data.frame is not a list, forcing data to be converted to data.frame is definitively not the solution. `pathways` should not be transformed after creation

Comment: Okay I found a mistake in the code when running the fgsea command I named the pathway incorrectly. However, after fixing this the error updated to: Error in is.finite(stats) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'list'